# How to draw a ListBoxItem Border over the ListBox Border in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I want to design a `ListBox` in a way that it looks like the selected item is highlighted outside the `ListBox`.
The `ListBox` has a border with 1px.
The `ListBoxItem` has a border with `"0 0 0 1"` and a highlight color when `IsSelected` is true.

When an item is selected its border on the right should be drawn over the border of the `ListBox`.

Here is an image demonstrating how it should look:

[image]

I tried to work with margins of the `ListBox` and `ListBoxItem` but the border of the `ListBoxItem` is cut off when reaching the border of the `ListBox`.

Is there a way to draw the `ListBoxItems` border over the `ListBox`'s border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could re-template both the `ListBox` (to have better control over margins etc) and the `ListBoxItem` to define the `BorderBrush` based on the `IsSelected` property.

> "its border on the right should be drawn over the border of the `ListBox`"

Well, you can work around this issue by not having a right `Border` at all for the `ListBox`. You could let each `ListBoxItem` be responsible for its right `Border` color. The `ListBox` in itself would look like this, without right `Border`:

[image: listbox without right border]

Now you only need to add a right `Border` on each `ListBoxItem`.

I ended up adding a `Margin="1 0 0 0"` adjustment in the inner `ItemsPresenter` to make the overall appearance smoother.

```xml
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Background="LightGray"
         BorderThickness="5 5 0 5"
         BorderBrush="Black">
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ItemsPresenter Margin="1 0 0 0"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border BorderThickness="0 0 5 0" Padding="5">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                            <Border.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Border">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Border.Style>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item1"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item2"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item3"/>
</ListBox>
```

Final look:

[image: screen capture of middle element selected]

You would have to add a lot of styling to achieve the full result but that's a way you could go.

Comment: Thanks.
Already thought about this solution but was hoping to avoid it since the border stops after the last ListboxItem. So you need a placeholder to keep the layout when using this in a dynamically filled navigation bar for example.

Comment: i think so. You could also use a grid to display a rectangle over your `ListBox` and find a way to bind the rectangle position to the selected listboxitem.

Comment: I appended a border control with the same BorderThickness as the ListBoxItems to the bottom of the ListBox. This way it looks like one control and can be stretched over the whole height. This worked better than expected.
Again thank you.